# Rails Random Active Record with Pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to find all records for a particular resource and display them in a random order, but with consistent pagination (you won't see the same record twice if you start paging). The display order should be randomized each time a user visits a page. I am using  [will_paginate](http://wiki.github.com/mislav/will_paginate/). Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store a random number in the user session cookies, then use that as seed for your database random function. This will be the same until the user closes their browser, and thus they will all see random, consistent records:

Get a large, random number:

```
cookies[:seed] = SecureRandom.random_number.to_s[2..20].to_i
```

Use this seed with e.g. MySQL:

```
SomeModel.all.order("RAND ?", cookies[:seed])
```

Comment: Update: I just realised one thing: You should probably make the random seed a part of your URLs, so that when a user stores a bookmark or saves a URL, it will not break pagination. You could then do seed ||= params[:seed] || session_seed

Answer (score 2):

This is not standard to my knowledge. I can see a use for this for instance for online tests.

I would suggest using a list per session/user. So when a user first goes to the page, you determine a list of ID's, in a random order, and all consecutive views you will use this list to show the correct order for that user/session.

I hope that the amount of rows is limited, and then this would make sense, for instance for tests. Also, when a user would leave a test before finishing it completely, she could continue where he left off. But maybe that is not relevant for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a database such as MySQL that has a randomize function such as `RAND()`, you can just add that to your pagination query like so:

```
Resource.paginate( ... :order => "RAND()" ... )
```

Check out some of the comments here regarding performance concerns: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1274-patch-add-support-for-order-random-in-queries

Comment: This won't work. When changing pages (i.e. 1 to 2) the query is run a second time, and it is possible to have a duplicate entry appear (an entry that was on page 1 also appearing on page 2).

Comment: I thought you meant you just wanted the entries on each page to be random. You could store the previously viewed pages in a session array and filter them out on the next request, but that seems really hacky and brittle.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem like a very good solution. I'm just a bit surprised something better doesn't exist. I've seen it implemented before in Ruby on Rails apps like http://sortfolio.com/.

Comment: I checked out Sortfolio and their listings are not random. If you refresh the page a few times, you will see the listings in the same order, just staring from a different offset. It's almost like going around in a circle, you can start at any point, but if you go around it in the same direction, you will always pass by the same points in a consistent order.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I didn't realize the site wasn't using random.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need help with this. One solution I've done in the past is to do the query with RAND but without pagination at first. Then store those record ID's and use that stored list to lookup and paginate from there. The initial RAND query could be set to only run when the page is 1 or nil. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I haven't taken a look at this in a long time and can't remember where it was used anymore! I appreciate the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I ended-up with this solution that worked for me on Postgres:

```
session[:seed] ||= rand() # should be between [-1..1]
seed = session[:seed] 
Product.select("setseed(#{seed})").first
Product.order('random()').limit(10).offset(params[:offset])
```